# IE8 not recognizing <span class="ui-button-text">?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, esri

I am working on a mapping application.  The following code block works great in IE10, Chrome, etc., but not IE8. It is a button which activates aerial layer, changes the text of the button to "street" (allows use of a new overlays button at that point), and toggles back if you hit "street" button.

```
btnStreetAerial_Click = function () {
var isAboveThreshold = (map.getScale() > 18055);

if ($("#btnStreetAerial").html() == '<span class="ui-button-text">Aerial</span>') {   
    //switch to aerial
    if (isAboveThreshold) {
        map.getLayer(mapEsriAerialLayerID).show();
    }
    else {
        map.getLayer(mapLocalAerialLayerID).show();
    }
    map.getLayer(swova.mapStreetID).hide();
    $("#btnAerialOverlay").show();
    $("#btnStreetAerial").html('<span class="ui-button-text">Street</span>');
}
else if ($("#btnStreetAerial").html() == '<span class="ui-button-text">Street</span>') {

    if (isAboveThreshold) {
        map.getLayer(mapEsriAerialLayerID).hide();
        map.getLayer(mapOverlay1LayerID).hide();
        map.getLayer(mapOverlay2LayerID).hide();
        map.getLayer(mapStreetID).show();
    }
    else {
        map.getLayer(mapLocalAerialLayerID).hide();
        map.getLayer(mapOverlay1LayerID).hide();
        map.getLayer(mapOverlay2LayerID).hide();
        map.getLayer(mapStreetID).show();
    }

    $("#btnAerialOverlay").hide();
    $("#btnStreetAerial").html('<span class="ui-button-text">Aerial</span>');
    $("#btnAerialOverlay").html('<span class="ui-button-text">Add Overlay</span>');
}
```

Again, this works fine in all browsers except for IE8, and my debug during IE8 won't make it past the if statement:

```
if ($("#btnStreetAerial").html() == '<span class="ui-button-text">Aerial</span>') {
```

And then the button click does nothing.  So, I'm assuming IE8 doesn't like `<span class="ui-button-text">`?

Any info would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: That seems like an odd way to go about this. Try `if($('#btnStreetAerial .ui-button-text').text() == 'Aerial')` instead. Different browsers may render the html slightly differently.

Comment: You should never ever base your conditionals on the markup returned, one whitespace in the wrong place and your screwed!

Comment: JasonP, thanks!  I'm still pretty new at this so it wasn't odd to me at the time, until someone teaches me a better way of course.  This did indeed solve my problem, if you post it as an answer, I can check it off.  Thanks again!